# scipy.sparse.csr_matrix replace values if not zero

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following situation:

I have two csr_matrices (in the form of a vector) of equal shape and I want to replace values of vector u if the corresponding value of vector v is not zero.

So:

```
u[i,0] = v[i,0] iff v[i,0] is not zero
```

Of course I can loop through the whole thing, but I was thinking that there should be a more pythonic solution to this which would also speed up the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: if I recall correctly , the csr_matrix object only store values different from 0. Can you post an example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yeah sure: So take the following example: u = csr_matrix((10,1)) and v = csr_matrix((10,1)) ... Now let's fill u[2,0] = 3 and u[3,0] = 4and v[2,0] = 4 ... Now I just want to replace the values of u iff there is a value in v at that specific point. So I would replace u[2,0] with v[2,0]. I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you will get is likely this, however this will not add new values to the sparsity pattern of `u`, only so it is iff `(u[i,j] is nonzero) and (v[i,j] != 0`)!

```
if not isinstance(u, csr_matrix):
    raise ValueError
# make sure that data is as expected. I hope this is all thats necessary. Not sure when it is necessary:
u.sum_duplicates()

col = np.arange(u.shape[0]).repeat(np.diff(u.indptr))
row = u.indices
# You could mask out specific rows/columns here too I guess

new_data = v[row, col]
new_data = np.asarray(new_data).squeeze() # probably not necessary, but doesn't hurt too
mask = new_data != 0
np.putmask(u.data, mask, new_data)

# or if you prefere, but a bit slower for the putmask call:
u.data[mask] = new_data[mask]
```

Sorry, was a bit back and forth, so if there is still something not quite right. I somewhat hope there is a neater solution...

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but the problem is that it also can be the case that I have to change the sparsity pattern. With my current loop I just changed it to a lil_matirx, maybe this would be a good apporoach here as well?

Comment: @ph_singer, I think so. You cannot change the sparsity pattern of a csr matrix efficiently anyways, so before you do even worse acrobatics that likely won't make it faster, convert to something that can be changed easily like the lil and convert back again.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the way I do it right now. So would your approach then also be suitable?